# Dynamically created options with optgroups and lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I trying to create dynamically created options with optgroups like this:

```
_.each( _.groupBy(productsCollection.toJSON(), 'menuname'), function( menuname, i ){

  $('#slcproduct').append($("<optgroup>").attr("label",i));

   _.each( menuname, function( product ){
        $('#slcproduct').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", product.id).text(product.product_title));
   });

   $('#slcproduct').append("</optgroup>");
});
```

So my options are properly created with optgroups but options aren't child  elements of optgroups. How Can I append options into optgroups elements ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You can't use jquery's append to add a partial tag. (Eg opening or beginning only) create the optgroup first and append the option elements to it... Then append the optgroups to the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
_.each(_.groupBy(productsCollection.toJSON(), 'menuname'), function(menuname, i) {
  var $optgroup = $("<optgroup>").attr("label", i);
  _.each(menuname, function(product) {
    $optgroup.append($("<option>").attr("value", product.id).text(product.product_title));
  });
  $('#slcproduct').append($optgroup);
});
```